# change global variable inside a function actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

i want code to change global variable inside a function in actionscript 3

eg :

```
var m:String;
function kkk()
{
  m = "kkkkkk";
}
trace(m);
```

Comment: you didn't run the function `kkk()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use global vars in as3 you will need to create a class to hold them in one place and the reference the vars in that class. [More Info](http://greenethumb.com/article/11/global-variables-in-as3/)

This is you global class (GlobalVarContainer.as)

```
package 
{
    public class GlobalVarContainer 
    {
        public static var vars:Object = {};
    }
}
```

This is how you access them

```
  import GlobalVarContainer;

  GlobalVarContainer.vars.groupingID  = 1
  GlobalVarContainer.vars.mediaID = 4
  GlobalVarContainer.vars.facultyID = 5
  GlobalVarContainer.vars.studentID = 2
```